# Emacs on MS Windows, typescript lsp server on wsl?

Tags: microsoft-windows, completion, ide, wsl

Long-time emacs user (38 years or so, not kidding). 
I'm on Windows 10, running native emacs 26.1.
I'm doing some Javascript/Typescript (`vue.js`) development, using WSL for that world, still with the native Windows Emacs. Works great for the most part, with a few path hassles now & then (`/mnt/c/foo` vs. `c:/foo`).

I just ran across the LSP idea (`https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode`) -- brilliant! I want to try that to get nice intellisense. I'll need to run the LSP server on WSL though, presumably using TCP (because all my JS/npm/tslint setup is there); has anyone done that? Will it work? Will I run into path or socket issues? Am I insane? I don't want to spend a day on a fool's errand if I can help it.

(Yeah, I could set up an X server and run WSL emacs over X but that's an extra hassle I'd like to avoid -- I'm pretty comfy with Windows emacs.)

Comment: I did try it -- created `c:/bin/typescript-language-server.cmd` that uses bash to start the WSL typescript-language-server, and use that in emacs lsp, but it gives errors on startup because of the project root being "c:/tmp" which of course is not a valid Linux/WSL path. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: You can transform Windows paths into WSL paths with the command `wslpath` (see the corresponding  [release notes of WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17063)). Does work nicely with local paths. AFAIK it has problems with unc-paths.

Comment: I am working with the opposite setup. Running Emacs on WSL with X-server. Works very well. From the Windows-side you have to start any program through the WSL bash. From the WSL side you can just start Windows applications. `mount -t drvfs` does mount any Windows drives including Windows shares and so on (even mounting Bitlocker encrypted drives works). The selection of the X-server is crucial. I am currently using [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/). That one just runs. Xming crashed too often.

Comment: I did some more work on it, transforming the paths going to the server. Not working yet, but some progress. Created an issue at https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/761 to track it.